SQL コピーして作ったテーブルとビューのパフォーマンスが悪い
SQL Server 13 & SSMS 18 です。
テーブルA と それを参照しているビュー B があり、Bに対して全件selectかけると40秒くらいで処理が返ってきます。
テーブルAのスキーマとデータをコピーしたテーブル A' を作りました。
また、ビューBのselect 文でAを参照しているところをA'に置換したビューB'を作りました。
ここでB'に対して全件selectをかけたところ20分経っても処理が返ってこないのであきらめて処理をキャンセルしました。
A'に全件selectをかけると問題なく結果が返ってきます。
BとB'にこれほどパフォーマンスに違いが出るのはどのような原因が考えられるでしょうか？

すいません、文字列の比較にcollateを付けたらパフォーマンスが改善したようです。

where句の文字列比較のところでcollate Japanese_CI_AS を付けたところパフォーマンスが改善しました。なぜこれでパフォーマンスが改善したのかはいまいちわかってませんが。。。
